# Center a MapKit view with a CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

How , how I can center the MapKit view with a CLLocationCoordinate2D?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(someLat, someLong);
```